# Find the biggest potential P (Particle) can have along this the curve C?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric, lagrange-multiplier, line-integrals

The curve $C$ is given by $x=t×cos(t)$, and $y=sin(t)$ $C$ $R^2$, 
where $t$  $∈$ $R≥0$.

1. Find the parametrization of the curve.
2. Find the biggest potential P can have along this curve.

This may be a part of the exercise as well:

- Vector field: $(x+2xy)i+(y+x^2-y^2)j$

I am not sure where to even begin. I am not sure how to apply what I know of Gradients, Line-integrals, Lagrange multipliers, etc to this problem. Any hints are very appreciated.

Comment: Is that all the information you have on $P$? Is it not under the influence of a vector field for example?

Comment: @Kuifje I do have a vector-field as well, but I wasn't sure if it was a part of this exercise or not. I guess it must be then since you are asking for one. I will update the OP.

Answer (score 1):

1. The answer is in the question:
   \begin{cases}
   x=t\cos t\\
   y=\sin t 
   \end{cases}
2. $P$ is under the influence of $\vec{F}=(x+2xy,y+x^2-y^2)$. A potential of $\vec{F}$ is a mapping $f(x,y):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
   $$
   \vec{F}=\nabla f
   $$
   Solving for $f$ yields
   $$
   f(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{2}+x^2y+\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{y^3}{3}+K,
   $$
   where $K$ is an arbitrary constant in $\mathbb{R}$. Now, you want to maximize this potential on the curve, i.e. you want to maximize $f(x,y)$ subject to
   \begin{cases}
   x=t\cos t\\
   y=\sin t 
   \end{cases}
   Substituting $x$ and $y$ by these expressions yields
   $$
   f(t)=\frac{t^2}{2}\cos^2(t)+t^2\cos^2(t)^2\sin(t)+\frac{\sin^2(t)}{2}-\frac{\sin(t)^3}{3}+K
   $$

This function, however, is unbounded:

[image]

So either I misinterpreted the question, either something is wrong.

Comment: 1). That is something I think is so weird. The question is given in that form yet asking me to parametrize it. It confuses me 2). I thought about doing almost what you have done. Substitute into the function and then derivate with respect to t, and set it to equal to zero (and I am not sure if that would have given me a correct answer or not though). The function is also continuing forever and that is also why I thought about using limits in some form?

Comment: Thanks for answering, even if your answer is wrong or not, I feel it points me in the right direction.

Comment: Kuifje, @DavidLund, maybe there's a typo? $t \sin(t)$ perhaps?